# Take the limit of a function inside a Lebesgue integral.

Tags: analysis, limits, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

I've been working on the Fundamental solution of Homogenous Heat Equation and I have problem with the following equality.

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \exp\left(\frac{-y^2}{4}\right)\phi\left(\sqrt{\epsilon}y, \epsilon\right)dy =  \phi(0,0) \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \exp\left(\frac{-y^2}{4}\right)dy.$$

How can I proof the following equality?

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \exp\left(\frac{-y^2}{4}\right)\phi\left(\sqrt{\epsilon}y, \epsilon\right)dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \exp\left(\frac{-y^2}{4}\right) \phi\left(\sqrt{\epsilon}y, \epsilon\right)\right)dy.$$

I want to know how I can formally proof that the limit goes inside the Lebesgue integral.

Notes:

- Suppose that $\phi$ is a test function.
- The integral is a Lebesgue integral.
- $\delta$ is Dirac Delta Distribution. ($\delta(\phi) = \phi(0), \phi \in D(\Omega)$ where $D$ is the space of Test Functions).
- $E$ is a fundamental solution of the differential operator with constant coefficients $P$ if $P(E) = \delta$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Comment: If $\phi$ is an element of $C_c^\infty$, then DCT applies.

Comment: How can I do that? I don't have a sequence of functions to apply DCT. I was thinking in DCT using $\{\phi(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}y, \frac{1}{n})\}_{n}$ as the function sequence but I don't know how to pass from a discrete limit to a continuous limit.

Comment: I finally understand how to solve this problem changing the limit of the function to sequences and apply DCT to all the sequences of functions.
* (Limit of a function in terms of sequences) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function

Comment: With well behaved functions, as these sample functions, in some cases, discrete and continuous limits are equivalent. Recall that you can answer your own question. This way, the post will be useful to someone else.

Comment: I followed THEOREM 9A from http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnilifolder/ili09.pdf